# SSIS Merge Insert Update

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration

I know how to merge insert/update in SQL Query

But I don't know how to merge with SSIS the same way.

If the record is not in the table2 i want to insert it, but if its already there i want it do look at the date and update with the newest data

Server1

Table1

```
Id   NameId   Name     date
------------------------------------
1       1     Thomas   2015-09-01
2       1     Fred     2015-09-03
-
```

Server2

Table2

```
Id   NameId    Name   date
```

Hope you guys can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Use a Lookup to the table prior to the insert. If the Lookup fails then this is a new record, so insert it. If the Lookup succeeds then use an "OLE DB Command" to update the record. 
e.g.

```
update xxxx set actnam = ?,loc =? ,tli = ?, where act = ?
```

You then map the parameters to the keys / other fields[image]

1. The Lookup. Use this to attempt to read the database table with the key fields.

2. You can drag a green line (successful read) from the lookup for the successful read. This should go to the "OLE DB Command"

3. You can drag a red line (read failed) to an "OLE DB destination" to insert the new record
4. You write an update SQL command (I normally try this out in SSMS first) to update a record. Once it is working in SSMS replace each fields with "?"
5. Copy this into the "OLE DB Command" and map the fields to the matching parameters

Comment: Thanks alot =). can you explane this more by step by step?